# Linux RRD database time differences

Tags: linux, x86, rrd

I have an ARM board and an x86 machine.
The rrdtool on the board is not compiled with graphical libs, so I can't generate graphs from RRDs on the target and just copy them on the x86 machine.
Instead I have to convert RRDs to XMLs on ARM, copy the XMLs on the x86 machine, rrdtool restore the XMLs in RRDs and then generate the PNGs on the x86 machine from the restored RRDs.

Because the rrdtool on the x86 is not the same version as the one on ARM, and I think it also has something to do with different time/date/timezone on x86, it's hard to follow the graphs for time related stuff.

Is there some other workflow I can use to get this right?

Comment: What do you want to get right? Install the same version of rrdtool and set the same timezone on both machines. I don't think this has anything to do with x86 vs ARM. And I don't think the timezone thing has anything to do with the rrdtool versions mismatch. This question is also probably more suited for unix.stackexchange.com as it's not a programming question (as standing).

Comment: I want to follow the course of some events on my target to investigate something, but it's difficult because I don't see it as it happens in the graph, but shifted somehow because the rddtool in my machine is based on another time reference. I was wondering if what I'm doing is a valid rrdtool use.. but I don't have other possibility. Yes, not really x86 vs ARM thing, I'm doing rrdtool dump/restore only to obtain the graphs.